# How to implement OnItemClickListener to Show an WebView from a ListView?

Tags: android

This is my ListView.

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favoritos_listView);
```

This list shows URLs, that came from an string-array, like this:

```
<string-array name="bookmark_urls">
    <item>http://www.google.com</item>
    <item>http://www.android.com/</item>
</string-array>
```

This is how I set the list:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aa = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.bookmark_titles, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
lv.setAdapter(aa);
```

The list has a listener to handle click in the items like this:

```
private OnItemClickListener onListClick = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
```

***Now, I want to open an WebView when the use clicks in an item. This WebView has to load the url that has been clicked in the list.***

How can I do it?

Comment: It seems that you got everything ready.. So what's your question? You just need to set your webview with the url which is related with your list item...

Comment: This is the problem. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Ok, you can get position of your clicked item on list. And you also know your array, which is R.array.bookmark_titles as i understand... So you know which item on this array clicked... You should find related url and use loadData method of webview to show that.

Comment: Ok, the position is passed as an argument. But the method to get this position should one from the ListView... or not?

Comment: Do you want to show a web page on click of a list item?

Comment: No. I don't know. I saw many examples in web, but I have to get the name and URLs from the string-array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get your question clearly. If you want to open a `webView` on list item click, this is how you can achieve it: (I am not near my dev machine, so not sure. Give this a try)

```
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        WebView webView = new WebView(v.getContext());
        String[] urls =  = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bookmark_urls);
        webView.loadUrl(urls[position]);
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }
```

And don't forget to add permission in your manifest file like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problema is that I have to get the URL from the string-array that is in my code. I'm trying to get the value, but it is not working.